# Get length of array inside object

Tags: javascript

i have the following object in javascript:

objectX which is an

```
Object {names : Array[14]}
```

im trying to get the length of this, but it returns undefined when i use objectX.length?

Im trying it in chrome debugger, and googling, anyone out there quickly let me know plz.

Comment: Do you want the number of properties in `Object`, or the length of `Object.names`?

Comment: length of names @BenM

Comment: See the answer posted already, then.

Comment: `objectX` | `objectx`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output it seems that the property name is `'name '`. See the differences in the console output:

```
> console.log({names: []});
Object {names: Array[0]}

> console.log({'names ': []});
Object {names : Array[0]}      // <- this looks like what you have
//           ^ note the space
```

So you'd have to do:

```
obj['names '].length
```

I suggest to fix the property name though, so that you can use `obj.name.length` instead.

Comment: thankyou, i just didn't think of that! grrrr spent last 20 minutes not even looking at that!

Comment: Next time you know ;)

Answer (score 7):

```
object.names.length
```

OR

```
object['names'].length
```

Comment: If i use objectx.names it returns undefined

Comment: Then your object is defined differently than the code you presented. (you'll need to replace "object" with whatever variable name you're using... perhaps `objectx.names.length`)

Comment: Okay if i use Object.keys(objectx).length, this returns me 1. But i want the length of names. Which it says is an array in chrome

Answer (score 0):

Fix your object notation:

```
var obj = {name:Array(14)};
alert(obj.name.length);

var obj = {name : [1, 2, 3, 4]};
alert(obj.name.length);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nSjgu/)

Comment: `Object {names : Array[14]}` is the output in Chrome's console. It's not actually JS code.

Comment: @FelixKling Ok, I misunderstood. Though I didn't think a space was valid in a property name.

Comment: You can use any string as property name. But if the property is not a valid *identifier*, then you cannot use *dot notation* (`a.b`) to access it, you have to use *bracket notation* (`a['b']`).

Comment: @FelixKling interesting. I learned something new today, thanks!