# How to render Array.length from inside of object to html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using jQuery and got an response from API by using $.ajax. I want to grab the Arrays length from inside each object and display that in the html page. This is what I have done so far.
Here is the API response, i did breakdown of the last object, which contains an array and player names:

```
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(1)} //1 injured player name
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(3)} //3 injured players names
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(5)} //5 injured players names
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(2)} //2 injured players names
>flaggedTokens:Array(2)
  >0:{offset: 0, token: "John", type:"UnknownToken"}
  >1:{offset: 1, token: "Adam", type:"UnknownToken"}
   length: 2
  >_proto_:Array(0)
  _type: "InjuredPlayers"
>_proto_: Object
```

In order to grab the length of the Array I can do any of these 2 methods according to this [Get length of array inside object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355106/get-length-of-array-inside-object)

```
console.log(response.flaggedTokens.length)
1
3
5
2
```

OR

```
console.log(response["flaggedTokens"].length)
1
3
5
2
```

My Failed Attempts: I assigned this output to a variable and tried to loop through and output by doing this:

```
$.ajax(gameResponse).done(function(response) {
  let injuredPlayers = response.flaggedTokens.length;
  let injuredPlayersArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < injuredPlayers.length; i++) {
     injuredPlayersArray.push(injuredPlayers[i])
  }
  $('.injured_players').html(injuredPlayersArray[i])
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
Team One Total number:  <span class="injured_players"></span>   //should be 1
Team Two Total number:  <span class="injured_players"></span>   //should be 3
Team Three Total number:<span class="injured_players"></span>   //should be 5
Team Four Toal number:  <span class="injured_players"></span>   //should be 2
</div>
```

Clearly I made some mistake which I can't seem to figure this out by myself. I was hoping if someone can guide me through the right direction.

Comment: Why are you returning inside the `for`?

Comment: `$('.injured_players').html(string)` will set the HTML of the *first* element with the class "injured_players" to the given string. Move that line of code inside the `for` loop and make it `$('.injured_players').eq(i).html(string)`. Remove the `return` line because that exits the function immediately.

Comment: Also, you should be getting errors in your console. `injuredPlayers` is a number, and numbers don't have a `length` property, so you should get an error on `i < injuredPlayers.length`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey No that wouldn't be an error, `(5).length` is just `undefined`, and `i < undefined` is just never true.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What does ".eq(i).html(string)" does in this case?

Comment: [`eq(i)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) gets the element at the index `i`. [`.html(string)`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) sets the HTML to whatever `string` is.

Comment: Good point @CherryDT.

Comment: There are a few problems in the given code, but there's also some problems in the overall design of the code that i tried to address in my answer. In the future, I would post more code  so we  can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @hamza765 I edited the question to display response properly. Shows "flaggedTokens: Array(2)" which has the name of injured player. I followed your instructions made changes to $(.ajax( ).done( )). Defined injuredPlayersArray outside of the ajax call and for loop outside. My console.log(injuredPlayersArray) prints out 4 empty array. Can't seem to get this to work and i don't see any error in the console either.

Comment: @NewCoder Can you tell me what the response is from your Ajax call? Is it a single object, or 4 objects? If it's 4 objects, do they come in a array?

Comment: @hamza765 When i console.log the response, this is how it displays in the dev tools, which i pasted above in the question. 4 objects, flaggedTokens holds an Array.
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(1)}
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(3)}
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(5)}
{_type: "InjuredPlayers", flaggedTokens: Array(2)}

Answer (score 0):

To start with, in your for loop, you are returning the push action, but that's unnecessary and it kills the loop on the first iteration. Also, you have already set the length of the array to a new variable, but then in your for loop, you try to get the length of the new variable. Lastly, you declare `injuredPlayersArray` in your ajax statement, but based on your post, you recieved 4 separate api responses, so it should be declared outside of your ajax call so that the array doesn't get overwritten with every new call. And you don't need a for loop as you're only working with one array. Here is what it should look like.

```
let injuredPlayersArray = [];
$.ajax(gameResponse).done(function(response) {
  let injuredPlayers = response.flaggedTokens.length;
  injuredPlayersArray.push(injuredPlayers)
})
```

Your other mistake is that you are trying to dynamically display the value in the proper html tag, but you're setting the value for every span tag at the same time. So after your loop is finished, they would all say `2`.

To fix that you can add a for loop after all of your api calls are completed (aka NOT inside a `$.ajax().done()`):

```
for (let i = 0; i < injuredPlayersArray.length; i++) {
  $('.injured_players').eq(i).html(injuredPlayersArray[i])
}
```

Note: `.eq()` returns a set of DOM elements that match the selector it is called upon. So `$('.injured_players')` matches 4 elements on your page and in your for loop, it finds the i-th element in that set (so index 0 is equal to the first span tag) and sets the html for that element.

Note 2: There is an assumption I had to make with your api calls. From the way your api call is storing the length of the flaggedToken array in your response, it seems each ajax response returns a single object with the array of injured players and that you will have 4 separate api calls. However, if that's not the case and the response returns a array of objects, you will need to iterate over the array and get the length *for every array in every object* one at a time. You can also then ignore my suggestion to move the declaration of `injuredPlayersArray` to outside the api call. And the second for loop i wrote would go *inside* the api call.